# Is it possible to convert a lead with a guest user?

Tags: lead-conversion, guest-user

I want to create a public site with a script which creates a new lead and sometimes converts it.

Is it even possible to it with the guest user? I don't see the 'Convert Leads' permission on the site guest profile. What are my choices?

```
try {
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(lid);
    lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(false);
    lc.setConvertedStatus('Converted_to_Opportunity');
    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
    System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
}
```

Error:

```
INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, Don't have sufficient access to Lead
```

Comment: Just confirming - you have put `without sharing` on the class (although I think based on this error that it won't fix it)

Comment: Try this gist I made to illustrate the process of escaping your current context: https://gist.github.com/rapsacnz/31dc4b142882cdf41787cea0b3faa697